# Issue listing object properties in Javascript

Tags: javascript, object

Basically I'm doing practice exercises where I need to list the properties of an object, and I've done this:

```
/* Write a JS program to list the properties of a JS object*/
console.log("EX 1");
let student = {
  name: "Dollar",
  job: "Unemployed",
  age: 18
};
let listing = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(student); // lists the properties of a JS object
console.log(listing.toString());
```

The output seems correct, but when I go to the resolution, it uses functions and if statements(if needed I'll provide them).

Is anything wrong with my code?

Comment: What does it mean "_when I go to the resolution it uses functions and if statements_"?

Comment: The answer to my problem uses a big chunk of code:

Comment: It's unclear what you expect as output and what is exactly the problem. Your code is not wrong. Doesn't it output what you expect? What do you expect?

Comment: The problem with many of those exercises is that they are ... old, dating from a time that there was maybe just one possible solution. Since then many (shorter) alternatives have been added to JavaScript, like you have used. No problem, you did well.

Answer (score 1):

In your example code, `listing` is already a list of the properties of the object, meaning the names of the keys of all key-value pairs in the dict-like structure.

There doesn't seem to be a good reason to use `.toString()` to convert the list itself into a string.

The goal of the comment "Write a JS program..." is probably simply to get you to write a for-loop to loop through the object, which is iterable.

```
for (let item of obj1) {
    console.log(item);
}
```